# Can we discuss the coding for MATLAB/Mathematica/SciPy/etc here?

Tags: discussion

Like how to vectorize the data structure, how to visualize the computational results in an elegant way, or can we share the code or subroutine here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say yes, definitely.  There have already been a few questions of this sort.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with David... As always, some effort must be shown in asking the question.